# How can I change the x axis scale (years to months) in a time series plot?

Tags: r, time-series

I have the following code and graph:

```
bleeds <- read.csv("C:/Users/aaron/OneDrive/MSc Operational Research/Dissertation/Bleeds.csv", header = TRUE)
bleeds

#Change date to object(date)
bleeds$Month <- as.Date(bleeds$Month, format = "%b")

## Transform data into time series

bleedts <- ts(bleeds$Number.of.Bleeds, frequency = 12, start = c(2019, 01), end = c(2021, 08))
bleedts
plot(bleedts)

bleeds$Month <- as.Date(bleeds$Month, format="%b")
str(bleeds$Month)

##Training and Test sets
training = window(bleedts, start = c(2019, 1), end = c(2020, 12))
testing = window(bleedts, start = c(2021, 1))

##Baseline (seasonal Naive) forecast
naive_forecast = snaive(training, h = length(testing), level = 95)
MAPE(naive$mean, testing) * 100

plot(bleedts, xlab = "Year", ylab = "Number of Bleeds", main = "Seasonal Naive Forecast",
         col = "blue", lwd=2)
lines(naive_forecast$mean, col = "red", lwd=2)
legend( x = "topleft",
        legend = c("Observed Number of bleeds", "Seasonal Naive Forecast"),
        col = c("Blue", "red"),
        lty = c(1, 1),
        lwd = c(2, 2),
        cex = 0.65)
```

and get the following graph
[Naive forecast vs Testing Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgviA.png)

I'm trying to change the time scale to months (Jan 2019 - August 2020) instead of the "2019, 2019.5" etc.

Comment: I'm guessing the language is R. If this is not correct, please amend the tags yourself for better visibility

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).